# How to traver a tree by using BFS to get the first NP value? NLTK

Tags: tree, nltk

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Barack) (NNP Obama))
    (VP
      (VBZ is)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (JJ 44th) (CC and) (JJ current) (NN president))
        (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NNP USA)))))
    (. .)))
```

How to get this sub tree value as it is the top NP tree?

```
(NP (NNP Barack) (NNP Obama))
```

Comment: Check : http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/util.html#breadth_first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can traverse tree and check if `isinstance(child, Tree)` and `child.label()=="NP"`

**Code:**

```
from nltk import Tree
from nltk.util import breadth_first

parse_str = "(ROOT (S (NP (NNP Barack) (NNP Obama)) (VP (VBZ is) (NP (NP (DT the) (JJ 44th) (CC and) (JJ current) (NN president)) (PP (IN of) (NP (DT the) (NNP USA))))) (. .)))"
t = Tree.fromstring(parse_str)

#alltrees = []

def getsubtrees(t):
    subtrees = []
    for subt in t:
        for child in subt:
            if isinstance(child, Tree) and child.label()=="NP":
                print child
                break    # Remove break to print all NPs

            if isinstance(child, Tree):
                subtrees.append(child)

    #alltrees.append(subtrees)
    if(len(subtrees)>1):
        getsubtrees(subtrees)

getsubtrees(t)
#print alltrees
```

**Output:**

```
(NP (NNP Barack) (NNP Obama))
```